# CSS SVG BackGround image in Django

Tags: css, django, svg

i used en template who use bootstrap 5,

in the css i can find :
`background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16'/><path fill='none' stroke='%23343a40' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' d='M2 5l6 6 6-6'/></svg>");`

it seems django don't find this url

The bootstrap 5.0 css for select form didn't work and show a standard select box not a bootstrap 5 look
.

thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the problem with svg's are that some applications/ browsers ignore them because of a missing line.

Add the svg code in to a separate file and save as svg.
On the top of the file add: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` this insures the svg is readable.

Now the only thing you have to do is add the `background-image` as an image itself like: `background-image: url("/images/name.svg");`